# Arbitrary manipulation of percentile given the mean and SD

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, quantiles

> Say I have math scores from a class of 50 students.
>
> What I know is the **mean** midterm score is $50$, and the **standard deviation** is $30$.
>
> So it is reasonable to assume that there is $50 * .16 = 8$ students whose score is greater than $50 + 30 = 80$, under the assumption of **normality**.
>
> But is it possible to **arbitrarily set the number of students** whose score is greater than $50 + 30 = 80$?
>
> For example, is it possible to manipulate the distribution so that the number of students whose score is greater than $80$ is only $0$, or $25$?

---

**My try**

Say the students' scores are from a parametric model.

Distributions such as **Exponential**, **Normal**, **Gamma**, **Logistic**, have at most two parameters, and we can uniquely determine the parameters **given the mean and variance.**

But this way is too ineffective for setting arbitrary number of the students whose score is more than $84\%$ percentile. given the midterm score mean and SD, because we have **limited number of distributions, and do not even know they can yield the number of specific percentile I want**.

I wonder is there any parametric model (i.e. distribution) that I can manipulate percentile given mean and variance. I guess some non-parametric approach can work, but I'm not quite good at that.

Comment: What are the bounds on possible test scores, if any?

Comment: Rather than playing with continuous distributions, you'll have more luck if you start with simple two-point and three-point distributions

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality may be helpful to you: it establishes definite bounds to the answer.